# Fitting data using a parametric differential equation

Tags: fitting, data, nonlinear

I was fit the data using differential equation(eqns) and pfun

I tried data fitting (I gave the parameter directly..a=22500, b=10^-22, c=2*10^-40 and scaling factor k=1.04 10^-36)

```
data = {{0, 0}, {3.69 10^12, 50.65}, {5.67 10^12, 
134.875}, {7.05 10^12, 225.275}, {9.03 10^12, 
381.65}, {1.09 10^13, 509.5}, {1.25 10^13, 595.3}, {1.45 10^13, 
815.325}, {1.76 10^13, 1225}, {2.10 10^13, 1624.125}, {2.46 10^13,
 2018.725}, {2.84 10^13, 2488.775}, {3.18 10^13, 
2942.9}, {3.68 10^13, 3630}, {4.39 10^13, 4558.65}, {5.52 10^13, 
5925.925}, {6.45 10^13, 7044.075}, {7.23 10^13, 
7972.2}, {8.18 10^13, 9119.575}, {9.38 10^13, 10545}, {1.06 10^14,
 11749.1}, {1.28 10^14, 13760.475}, {1.42 10^14, 
15055.65}, {1.57 10^14, 16484.475}};

eqns = {n'[t] == 22500 L - 10^-22 n[t]^2 - 2.0 10^-40  n[t]^3 , n[0] == 0};

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(30\)]\(n[s]^2 \[DifferentialD]s\)\), {t, 0, 30}, {L}]
```

then plot the data

```
Show[LogLogPlot[1.04 10^-36  pfun[L], {L, 10^12, 2*10^14},  
AxesLabel -> {l, K \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(30\)]\(n[l, t]^2 \[DifferentialD]t\)\)}, ImageSize -> Large, 
PlotStyle -> Red], ListLogLogPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black], 
LogLogPlot[0.45 10^-23*L^2, {L, 10^12, 2*10^14}], LabelStyle -> 
Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]]
```

[image]

---

after, I want to fit the data (by computer directly)

```
eqns = {n'[t] == a L - b n[t]^2 - c n[t]^3 , n[0] == 0};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(30\)]\(n[
   t]^2 \[DifferentialD]t\)\), {t, 0, 30}, {a, b, c, k}];

fit = FindFit[data, 
k*pfun, {{a, 22500}, {b, 10^-22}, {c, 2.0 10^-40},{k, 1.04 10^-36}}, L, 
Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}] // Quiet
```

But the **Findfit** code errors appear..

**For get rid of the errors, how to rivise the above code?**

**If you give me an another fitting code, I'll accept thankfully.**

Thank you.

Comment: What do the errors tell you?

Comment: Your last `pfun` depends on 5(!) parameters `{a,b,c,k,L}`.  The second argument of `FindFit`should be something like `k*pfun[a, b, c, k, L]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the integral evaluation within ParametricNDSolve is slow due to symbolic processing.  I removed it from ParametricNDSolve and evaluated the integral with NIntegrate turning SymbolicProcessing->0. It was >100x faster on my machine doing it this way. I also like using non-dimensional scaling to keep values closer to 1.

I use the subscript $d$ to relate parameters with dimension to their dimensionless counterparts as shown below.

$$\begin{gathered}
  L = \frac{{{L_d}}}{{{L_{\max }}}} \hfill \\
  a = \frac{{{a_d}{L_{\max }}{t_{\max }}}}{{{n_0}}} \hfill \\
  b = {b_d}{n_0}{t_{\max }} \hfill \\
  c = {c_d}n_0^2{t_{\max }} \hfill \\
  {n_0} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {K{t_{\max }}} }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Since the data appear fairly evenly spread out on a log-log scale, I will also do the fit on a log-log scale to achieve a better weighting.  Here is how I recast the example given in the OP.

```
data = {{0, 0}, {3.69 10^12, 50.65}, {5.67 10^12, 
    134.875}, {7.05 10^12, 225.275}, {9.03 10^12, 
    381.65}, {1.09 10^13, 509.5}, {1.25 10^13, 595.3}, {1.45 10^13, 
    815.325}, {1.76 10^13, 1225}, {2.10 10^13, 1624.125}, {2.46 10^13,
     2018.725}, {2.84 10^13, 2488.775}, {3.18 10^13, 
    2942.9}, {3.68 10^13, 3630}, {4.39 10^13, 4558.65}, {5.52 10^13, 
    5925.925}, {6.45 10^13, 7044.075}, {7.23 10^13, 
    7972.2}, {8.18 10^13, 9119.575}, {9.38 10^13, 10545}, {1.06 10^14,
     11749.1}, {1.28 10^14, 13760.475}, {1.42 10^14, 
    15055.65}, {1.57 10^14, 16484.475}};
(* Scale data max L value *)
sdata = data;
sdata[[All, 1]] = data[[All, 1]]/Max@data[[All, 1]];
(* Data looks equally spaced on log-log scale *)
(* so let's scale it (Note: remove {0,0}) *)
lldata = N@Log@sdata[[2 ;; -1]];
(* create parameters for non-dim scaling *)
tmax = 30;
Kfac = 1.04 10^-36;
scalefac = 1;
Lmax = Max@data[[All, 1]];
n0 = 1/Sqrt[Kfac tmax];
(* Scaled equations *)
eqns = {n'[t] == 
    tmax/n0 (22500 Lmax L - 10^-22 n0^2 n[t]^2 - 
       2.0 10^-40 n0^3 n[t]^3) , n[0] == 0};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[ eqns, n, {t, 0, 1}, {L}];
f = Function[{l}, 
   Log@NIntegrate[(pfun[Exp[l]][t])^2, {t, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], Listable];
Show[Plot[f[l], {l, -4, 0.5},  
  AxesLabel -> {l, K \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(30\)]\(n[l, 
         t]^2 \[DifferentialD]t\)\)}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[lldata, PlotStyle -> Black], 
 Plot[Log[0.45 10^-23*Lmax^2*Exp[l]^2], {l, -4, 0.5}], LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]]
(* Show scaled equations *)
eqns // Simplify
(* {(n^\[Prime])[t]\[Equal]591.9441354553654` \
L-0.0005370861555295748` n[t]^2-0.00019230769230769236` n[t]^3,n[0]\
\[Equal]0} *)
```

[image: OP Example Recast]

It looks we have recast the problem to the mimic the original state.  Now, we can formulate the problem to fit $a,b,c,sf$ just using FindFit out-of-the-box.

```
(* Dimensionless Equations *)
eqns = {n'[t] == a L - b n[t]^2 - c n[t]^3 , n[0] == 0};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[ eqns, n, {t, 0, 1}, {a, b, c, L}];
ffull = Function[{a, b, c, sf, l}, 
   sf Log@NIntegrate[(pfun[a, b, c, Exp[l]][t])^2, {t, 0, 1}, 
      Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}], Listable];
(* rewrite in more typical model form *)
model[a_, b_, c_, sf_][l_] := ffull[a, b, c, sf, l]
{time, fit} = 
 Quiet@FindFit[lldata, 
    model[a, b, c, sf][
     l], {{a, 500}, {b, 0.005} , {c, 0.0005}, {sf, 1}}, l] // 
  AbsoluteTiming
(*  {3.18,{a->440.,b->0.00719,c->0.000705,sf->1.13} *)
Show[Plot[model[a, b, c, sf][l] /. fit, {l, -4, 0.5},  
  AxesLabel -> {Log@l, Log[sf \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(1\)]\(n[l, 
          t]^2 \[DifferentialD]t\)\)]}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], ListPlot[lldata, PlotStyle -> Black], 
 Plot[Log[0.45 10^-23*Lmax^2*Exp[l]^2], {l, -4, 0.5}], LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]]
(* Rescale Parameters Back to Dimensioned Forms *)
nd = {a, b, c, L};
scalefactors = {Lmax tmax/n0, n0 tmax, n0^2 tmax, 1/Lmax};
(nd /. fit) ~Times~(1/scalefactors)
(*  {16700.,1.34*10^(-21),7.33*10^(-40),(1.57*10^(14)) L} *)
```

[image: Actual Fit]

The fit looks pretty good and it took about 3 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The modified script below doesn't gives formal errors but keeps a lot of time processing before outputting some messages now linked to numerical problems.

```
eqns = {n'[t] == a L - b n[t]^2 - c n[t]^3 , n[0] == 0};
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(30\)]\(n[
   t]^2 \[DifferentialD]t\)\), {t, 0, 30}, {a, b, c, k, L}];

fit = FindFit[data, k*pfun[a, b, c, k, L], 
{{a, 22500}, {b, 10^-22}, {c, 2.0 10^-40}, {k, 1.04 10^-36}}, L, 
Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}] // Quiet
```